# How to solve input duplicate problem In C

Tags: c, scanf

when i input base value, it will not be recognized first in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
    float base, height, area;

    printf("area of triangle=?\n");
    printf("base=");
    scanf("%f\n", &base);
    printf("height=");
    scanf("%f\n", &height);
    area = base*height / 2;

    printf("area = %f\n", area);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 primary problems in your code.

**(1)** Do not include `'\n'` in your format specifier. Format specifiers such as `"%f"` skip *whitespace* by default. So use (subject to #2):

```
scanf("%f", &base)
```

**(2)** Validate EVERY user input by ***checking the return*** of the input function used. What happens if the user reached for the `'4'` key by hit `'R'` my mistake? What happens then? (if it is the 1st digit -- undefined behavior as you blindly assume the input succeeded). Instead, validate the return, e.g.

```
    if (scanf("%f", &base) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid float - base.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float base, height, area;

    fputs ("area of triangle=?\nbase=", stdout);
    if (scanf("%f", &base) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid float - base.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    fputs ("height=", stdout);
    if (scanf("%f", &height) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid float - height.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    area = base * height / 2.;

    printf ("\narea = %f\n", area);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** nit - there is no need to use the variadic `printf` function if there are no conversions involved, simply use `fputs` (or just `puts` if you want a default `'\n'` at the end). A good compiler will optimize this for your, but showing an understanding of what the proper tool for the job is has merit)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trianglearea
area of triangle=?
base=3
height=4

area = 6.000000
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf using only format

```
scanf("%f",&base);
```

Comment: You need to explain the change you've made and why.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("base=");
scanf("%f", &base);
printf("\n");
printf("height=");
scanf("%f", &height);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: You need to explain what changes you've made and why.

Comment: print new line after scanf() .